# SQL Server database mirroring and primary key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, mirroring, database-mirroring

"It is better to use `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` type in tables when you use database mirroring" - is it myth?

What may be a reason to use unique primary key for mirroring purpose (single database mirroring case)?

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reason at all.

In *mirroring* only one database is in-use so there are no collision issues.

Is someone confusing this with *replication* where several sites are in-use and synch to each other? uniqueidentifier has a use here (and is mandatory in some cases) but still *not* as clustered index. And you use NOT FOR REPLICATION clauses on triggers and IDENTITY etc